# (emgucv) Error BruteForceMatcher is non-generic?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, surf

guys, recentlty I am doing a C# project with the SURF algorithm of emgucv.

I met a problem with this sentence:

```
BruteForceMatcher<float> matcher = new BruteForceMatcher<float(DistanceType.L2);
```

Error is:

> **The non-generic type 'Emgu.CV.Features2D.BruteForceMatcher' cannot be used with type arguments**

The example of emgucv is written like this, I just copy this sentence, and I try to check the definition of bruteForeceMatcher, it is non-generic, but how can the example run?

*I guess there is maybe new version of Opencv? This method duplicated? Can somebody help me?*
Thank you !

Comment: I think you want the [`BFMatcher`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/a8eacb84-05cc-c15c-3582-e7d9f848ff17.htm) class

Comment: Yes, i think you are right for the version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem!

For all the beginers who also have this problem. Please remember: Foucus on the version of Emgucv. Dont make the same ***STUPID*** problem like me.

Before YOU COPY any code from there, **DONT IGNORE** the **system requires** and the **verison** requiments of opencv or Emgucv. Because they will change some basic syntax.